# Filesystem and mount point

Tags: mount, disk-usage, storage

I am confused with which path should I give to store the file.

```
host# df -h
Filesystem                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2                                       5.9G  5.0G  574M  90% /
/dev/xvda4                                       7.9G  147M  7.4G   2% /mnt
```

By default it is storing the data in `/`. I need to give other disk location to store the file when my default location is full.

So how can I give the path? Is it something like this: `/dev/xvda4/`?
Or this way: `/mnt/mydir`

Comment: Let's see your '/etc/fstab'.  It looks to me like your disk is not partitioned effectively, what does "fdisk -l /dev/xvda" show? It seems a waste of space to have 7.9G standing by for mounts that might not even happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `/mnt` in your case as it is on the second partition which has free space.

You do not want to allow the root (`/`) partition to get full as you will run into trouble.  For example, during the next system update your package manager may download many packages and crash while trying to install them, simply due to the lack of disk space.

The *default* location for your files should be your home directory.  For example, if you log in as user `navaz` then your home directory is `/home/navaz`.  Your general storage area should be this and not root (`/`).

In your case `/home` is a sub-directory of the root (`/`) so you would not stop the disk filling up by saving files to `/home`.  However, if you mount the 8GiB partition as `/home` instead of `/mnt` then you could use the space on that to save your files which would free up much of the root partition.

Comment: Thank You @garethTheRed . Well Explained. It cleared my doubt.